# How to fix design pattern error for cron in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-cron

I would like to make a cron that runs every day from 8am to 11pm.

```
const cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('0 8/5 * * *', () => {
    console.log('run the application from 8 am to 11 pm');

});
```

but when I try to execute this file it gives this error:

```
throw new Error(`${patterns[2]} is an invalid expression for hour`);
```

I'm using node-cron. Can someone help me?

Comment: If you want to run from 8 to 11, use `8-23`, not `8/5`

Comment: Why does the log message say 9am instead of 8am?

Comment: `/number` can only be used after a range or `*`. It can't be used after a single number. It means to run every Nth period during that range.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to run it everyday at every hour from 08:00 am to 11:00 pm.

```
0 08-23 * * *
```

You can check the validation in [here](https://crontab.guru/#0_08-23_*_*_*).